# Predicting Item Ratings with the Log Likelihood Ratio

Tags: python, recommender-system

I'm trying to infer prediction ratings from an item-item similarity matrix where the similarity score is calculated via the log-likelihood ratio (LLR). I'm using this code snippet to calculate the LLR (taken from this [medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-production-ready-recommender-system-3c932752f8ea) article):

```
import numpy as np

def xLogX(x):
    return x * np.log(x) if x != 0 else 0.0

def entropy(x1, x2=0, x3=0, x4=0):
    return xLogX(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) - xLogX(x1) - xLogX(x2) - xLogX(x3) - xLogX(x4)

def LLR(k11, k12, k21, k22):
    rowEntropy = entropy(k11 + k12, k21 + k22)
    columnEntropy = entropy(k11 + k21, k12 + k22)
    matrixEntropy = entropy(k11, k12, k21, k22)
    if rowEntropy + columnEntropy < matrixEntropy:
        return 0.0
    return 2.0 * (rowEntropy + columnEntropy - matrixEntropy)

def rootLLR(k11, k12, k21, k22):
    llr = LLR(k11, k12, k21, k22)
    sqrt = np.sqrt(llr)
    if k11 * 1.0 / (k11 + k12) < k21 * 1.0 / (k21 + k22):
        sqrt = -sqrt
    return sqrt

rootLLR(100, 10, 10, 50000) # 36.18239222320234
```

To get a better understanding of the LLR check out this [article](http://tdunning.blogspot.com/2008/03/surprise-and-coincidence.html) by Ted Dunning. The issue I'm having is the LLR scores are not bounded (higher is better). For example, using the cosine similarity, the scores are bound from -1 to 1. Whereas with LLR this is not the case so calculating the weighted sum for rating prediction is difficult.

I've seen this [paper](https://aircconline.com/ijcsea/V6N3/6316ijcsea01.pdf) (page 6) which normalises the LLR score but does not state how. The table from the paper is shown below.

[image]